# stateless Widget Keeps Rebuilding

Tags: android, flutter, dart, state-management, statelesswidget

I'M currently working on a to-do app following a tutorial
this is the checkbox part

I'm trying to lift it's state up the tree, but when I do so the stateless widget just keeps rebuilding non stop ,
I tried adding **key** , adding **const** converting it to **stateful** but nothing seems to work
it also doesn't provide me with any kind of error or  exceptions messages

note : when I set the **onChecked** to **null** the statelessWidget runs twice when it should only build once..

below is the code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
    }
    
    class _TaskTileState extends State {
      bool isChecked = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "Complete Todoey",
            style: TextStyle(
                decoration: isChecked == true
                    ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                    : TextDecoration.none),
          ),
          trailing: TaskCheckBox(
              checkBoxState: isChecked,
              toggleCheckBoxState:
                  (bool checkBoxState) {
                Future.delayed(Duration.zero,
                    () async {
                  setState(() {
                    print(
                        "===================$isChecked==============$checkBoxState======================");
                    isChecked = checkBoxState;
                  });
                });
              }),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class TaskCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
      const TaskCheckBox(
          {Key? key,
          required this.checkBoxState,
          required this.toggleCheckBoxState})
          : super(key: key);
    
      final bool checkBoxState;
      final Function toggleCheckBoxState;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(
            "=====================================$checkBoxState+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        return Checkbox(
          value: checkBoxState,
          onChanged:
              null, // toggleCheckBoxState(checkBoxState),
        );
      }
    }
```

a snip from the console output :

```
 
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/flutter ( 3401): ===================false==============false======================
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/flutter ( 3401): ===================false==============false======================
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/flutter ( 3401): ===================false==============false======================
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/flutter ( 3401): ===================false==============false======================
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/flutter ( 3401): ===================false==============false======================
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

a snip from the output when **onChanged** is set to **null** :

```
Restarted application in 2,694ms.
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
I/flutter ( 3401): =====================================false+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of setState is to tell the framework that a variable in the state has changed and the widget needs to be rebuilt to reflect that change. So calling setState calls the build function again, which in your case recalls your Future, which calls setState again, which triggers build and so on.

To fix this you could get rid of async function with `Future.delayed` since it's not needed there at all as well as putting print outside your setstate function.